# Bad Access signal when using core data with Swift

Tags: macos, core-data, swift

I have an OS X application that uses the default Core Data template using Swift.

I've added a NSArrayController object to the dock and bound it's `Managed Object Context` to the App Delegate's `managedObjectContext`.

However when the application is run, this causes a 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)' signal to appear at this line of code

```
let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
```

I don't have this problem when I follow the same steps for an Objective-C program, so i'm guessing this has something to do with Swift. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using the latest Xcode 6.1 Beta on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

`persistentStoreCoordinator` is a `lazy` var in AppDelegate. That means it gets evaluated and initialized when it is  needed the first time at program execution.

Search your AppDelegate class for

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    ...
}
```

and place a breakpoint at the beginning. Then single-step through the code to examine the point where the error occurs to gain more information on what's wrong.